# Setting up a lookup attribute in an entity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have an entity called *Samples*. Inside that I have many fields, one of them is a *ProjectLocation* drop down list.

Now I use this code to insert a new instance of type *Sample* in the CRM through WCF.

```
Entity sample = new Entity("new_sample");
sample.Attributes["name"]= "Ahmed";
```

This works but when I want to enter the *ProjectLocation* I don't have any idea how should it be accomplished.

This doesn't work.

```
Entity projectLoc = service.Retrieve("projectlocation", (new guid here), columnset)
sample.Attributes["new_projectlocation1"] = projectLoc
```

What can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your code to return an [EntityReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.entity.toentityreference.aspx), here is the updated code:

```
Entity projectLoc=service.Retrieve("projectlocation",(new guid here),columnset) //retrieves a correct projectloc. 
sample.Attributes["new_projectlocation1"]=projectLoc.ToEntityReference(); //Now it'll work
```

Answer (score 1):

Lookups are instances of `EntityReference` not `Entity`. I've always imagine a lookup as a pointer (via a GUID) to an entity, instead of the entity itself. But then again, my diploma work was in C++ so I'm supposed to be brain-washed regarding pointers. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an `EntityReference`.

```
sample.Attributes["new_projectlocation1"] 
  = new EntityReference("projectlocation", new guid here);
```